# preventDefault() doesn't work after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using PreventDefault(), for the submit event, in case they do not find changes in my input, so far so good, the problem is that after making the AJAX request, (I do not reload the page, only DIV), the user can press the submit button if you make any changes.

I would like the PreventDefault to continue working after each registration after the AJAX request, since it is only activated again if the page is reloaded

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if I can see your code but instead of preventDefault(), you need to manage state changes within your input and then based on the state (whether it is empty or has string or type of data you are getting), you can disable or enable your button.